# How can I add all the existing content types into a dropdown list?

Tags: 8, nodes

In Drupal 8, I am using the *Config Pages* module to set up a configuration page for a custom module. How can I add all the existing content types into a dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom form, in add `$options` to your content type list field.
the following snippet get list of all the content type names for you;

```
   $node_types = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple();
    // If you need to display them in a drop down:
    $options = [];
    foreach ($node_types as $node_type) {
      $options[$node_type->id()] = $node_type->label();
    }
```